# How to add flood guard to 3.5” sink drain?

Tags: plumbing, basement, flooding

I have a laundry sink that backs up with storm sewer water occasionally.  Looking for a simple way to add a flood guard to the sink.

The floor drains have 3” float flood guards that work well but I don’t know what would fit on the sink drain.  I’m getting a new sink that seems to come with a 3.5” drain kit but I don’t see float valves at the 3.5” size, only 3 or 4”

My existing sink has the 1.5” smaller pipe.

Comment: I'm not sure what a "float flood guard" is, but I'd think that a 1-way check valve in the drain line should do the trick.

Comment: @FreeMan I suspect some kind of backflow preventer.  OP, can you elaborate on the "float flood guards" you mention?

Comment: 3.5” drain *strainer* kit - which have 1-1/2" take offs. "My existing sink has the 1.5” smaller pipe." - which prob feeds a 2" in the wall. So you're looking for a **2" back flow preventer**, and how to do drywall. - Really, you should be busting up the concrete where the pipe leaves the house and put flapper valve in there for the whole house.

Comment: The float type flood guard has a small float the moves up with backflow to create a seal like this item https://www.homedepot.com/p/General-Pipe-Cleaners-Flood-Guard-4-in-10-cm-Float-Model-4FH/319113411 @FreeMan